# use of escape sequence

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiimage

i want to show image height and width in a format a*b.for that i am using following code.problem is that label not show proper value where as height and ImagesizeWidth variable show correct value.

```
UIImage *newImage = image;
NSString *c= @"*";
int height = image.size.height;
int ImageSizeWidth = image.size.width;

//int size = image.size.height * image.size.width;
pixelInformation.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%a%d",ImageSizeWidth,c,height];
```

can anyone help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `%@` format specifier of Objective-C objects. They need to have `description` implemented.

So the last line should be,

```
pixelInformation.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@%d",ImageSizeWidth,c,height];
```

It's not `%a`. And you can directly put a `*` in the string though.

```
pixelInformation.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d*%d",ImageSizeWidth,height];
```